# Is it better to do fixed-length Lempel Ziv Encoding or variable length?

Tags: digital-communications, coding

I performed variable-length LZW encoding in Matlab on a large set of text where my dictionary looks like this (size = 28):

```
dictionary = {'#', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ' '};
```

and I calculated the average codeword length to be $\approx 4.13$ but I had a hard time trying to decode it since the codeword length was not fixed and this lead to many errors after just the first few characters. So then I encoded my text by using fixed length coding (zero padded to make every codeword the same length) and I was also able to decode it rather easily. But this lead to a problem since the average codeword length became $\approx 4.97$ which is almost equivalent to never having done any coding in the first place. So my question is does anyone have any resources using which I can make a decoder for variable length LZW encoding?

**Update:** For fixed-length coding I calculated the average codeword length by simply taking the total number of bits in my binary encoded sequence and then dividing them by the total number of characters in my text sequence. This I think is correct but I also used the same method to calculate the average code word length for the variable-length case which I have now realized is definitely the incorrect way. So my question is how can I calculate the average code word length for the variable case? Do I only store the codes for the characters in my initial dictionary and multiply them by their probability of occurrence?

Comment: What is the entropy of your text sequence? If your entropy is larger than $4.13$ then your original implementation might have been wrong.

Comment: The entropy is roughly $4.1$ so I am fairly certain that my original encoding was implemented properly!

Comment: @AhsanYousaf Note that a text sequence does not have entropy; it has information. Entropy is a property of sources, not sequences.

Comment: @CaporalFourrier LZW has variants with fixed-length and variable-length codewords. If your program doesn't work, I'd suspect a coding bug rather than a problem with the algorithm itself.

Comment: @MBaz If the text sequence is fixed one can easily determine the probability of each possible character based on their frequency of occurrence. Then, based on these probabilities, one can easily compute the **entropy** of the sequence which I guess becomes a source if you fix the sequence.

Comment: @CaporalFourrier What you show are the first few entries of the dictionary which are equivalent to the Alphabet. The dictionary would contain all possible substrings as they are formed by following the text char-by-char. Can you please confirm how are you calculating "the average codeword length"? Variable code length is just an encoding for your dictionary indices and they are based on [prefix codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_code#Prefix_codes).

Comment: I removed everything that is not in the dictionary from my text. Yes, I was calculating the average codeword length incorrectly for the variable-length encoding. I will update the question to reflect that.

Comment: @AhsanYousaf Indeed it is easy to compute an "entropy" that way. It's still incorrect.